# Does the momentum from the arms transfer to the body if you stop it when jumping?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws

So if you jump vertically and you swing your arms forward to give them an angular momentum and then your arms reaches it's limit. Does the angular momentum transfer to the body as a whole causing a back flip? I know the angular momentum has to be conserved. $L=I\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

No, Bending your arms will merely provide a way to decrease your moment of inertia hence increasing  your angular velocity. 
$$\tau_{ext}=0=\frac{dL}{dt}$$
$$\Delta L=0$$
$$I_1\omega_1=I_2w_2$$
For a Back flip,a vertical jump won't be helping your cause.